# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException Input string '0.64' is not a valid integer

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, azure-cognitive-services

I keep getting a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException that says "Input string '0.64' is not a valid integer. I can't figure out how to fix the issue. I am following a C# tutorial on [Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com), but it is from a few years ago and the instructions are outdated.

I am trying to use the Azure Cognitive Services Text Sentiment Analysis API.

ETA: `NewsResult` class (added at end)

Here is my main method file:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Net.Http;
    
    namespace SoccerStats
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);
                var fileName = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "SoccerGameResults.csv");
                var fileContents = ReadSoccerResults(fileName);
                fileName = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "players.json");
                var players = DeserializePlayers(fileName);
                var topTenPlayers = GetTopTenPlayers(players);
                foreach (var player in topTenPlayers)
                {
                    var playerName = $"{player.FirstName} {player.SecondName}";
                    Console.WriteLine(playerName);
                    List<NewsResult> newsResults = GetNewsForPlayer(string.Format("{0} {1}", player.FirstName, player.SecondName));
                    SentimentResponse sentimentResponse = GetSentimentResponse(newsResults);
                    foreach (var sentiment in sentimentResponse.Docs)
                    {
                        foreach (var result in newsResults)
                        {
                            if (result.Headline == sentiment.Id)
                            {
                                double score;
                                if (double.TryParse(sentiment.Sentiment, out score))
                                {
                                    result.SentimentScore = score;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    foreach (var result in newsResults)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sentiment Score: {0} Date: {1:f}, Headline: {2}, Summary: {3} \r\n", result.SentimentScore, result.DatePublished, result.Headline, result.Summary));
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
                fileName = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "topten.json");
                SerializePlayersToFile(topTenPlayers, fileName);
            }
    
            public static string ReadFile(string fileName)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
    
            public static List<GameResult> ReadSoccerResults(string fileName)
            {
                var soccerResults = new List<GameResult>();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    string line = "";
                    reader.ReadLine();
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        var gameResult = new GameResult();
                        string[] values = line.Split(',');
                        DateTime gameDate;
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(values[0], out gameDate))
                        {
                            gameResult.GameDate = gameDate;
                        }
                        gameResult.TeamName = values[1];
                        HomeOrAway homeOrAway;
                        if (Enum.TryParse(values[2], out homeOrAway))
                        {
                            gameResult.HomeOrAway = homeOrAway;
                        }
                        int parseInt;
                        if (int.TryParse(values[3], out parseInt))
                        {
                            gameResult.Goals = parseInt;
                        }
                        if (int.TryParse(values[4], out parseInt))
                        {
                            gameResult.GoalAttempts = parseInt;
                        }
                        if (int.TryParse(values[5], out parseInt))
                        {
                            gameResult.ShotsOnGoal = parseInt;
                        }
                        if (int.TryParse(values[6], out parseInt))
                        {
                            gameResult.ShotsOnGoal = parseInt;
                        }
    
                        double possessionPercent;
                        if (double.TryParse(values[7], out possessionPercent))
                        {
                            gameResult.PosessionPercent = possessionPercent;
                        }
    
                        soccerResults.Add(gameResult);
                    }
                }
                return soccerResults;
            }
    
            public static List<Player> DeserializePlayers(string fileName)
            {
                var players = new List<Player>();
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    players = serializer.Deserialize<List<Player>>(jsonReader);
                }
    
                return players;
            }
    
            public static List<Player> GetTopTenPlayers(List<Player> players)
            {
                var topTenPlayers = new List<Player>();
                players.Sort(new PlayerComparer());
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var player in players)
                {
                    topTenPlayers.Add(player);
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 10)
                        break;
                }
                return topTenPlayers;
            }
    
            public static void SerializePlayersToFile(List<Player> players, string fileName)
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, players);
                }
            }
    
            public static string GetGoogleHomePage()
            {
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    byte[] googleHome = webClient.DownloadData("https://www.google.com");
    
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(googleHome))
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public static List<NewsResult> GetNewsForPlayer(string playerName)
            {
                var results = new List<NewsResult>();
                using var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "#####");
                byte[] searchResults = webClient.DownloadData(string.Format("https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/news/search?q={0}&mkt-en-us", playerName));
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(searchResults))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    results = serializer.Deserialize<NewsSearch>(jsonReader).NewsResults;
    
                }
                return results;
            }
    
            public static SentimentResponse GetSentimentResponse(List<NewsResult> newsResults)
            {
                var sentimentResponse = new SentimentResponse();
                var sentimentRequest = new SentimentRequest();
                sentimentRequest.Documents = new List<Document>();
                foreach (var result in newsResults)
                {
                    sentimentRequest.Documents.Add(new Document { Id = result.Headline, Text = result.Summary });
                }
                using var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "########");
                webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
                string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sentimentRequest);
                byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestJson);
                byte[] response = webClient.UploadData("https://<endpoint>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/text/analytics/v3.1/sentiment", requestBytes);
                string sentiments = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                sentimentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SentimentResponse>(sentiments);
                return sentimentResponse;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my SentimentResponse class:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    namespace SoccerStats
    {
        // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
        public class ConfidenceScores
        {
            [JsonProperty("negative")]
            public int Negative { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("neutral")]
            public int Neutral { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("positive")]
            public int Positive { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Relation
        {
            [JsonProperty("ref")]
            public string Ref { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("relationType")]
            public string RelationType { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Target
        {
            [JsonProperty("confidenceScores")]
            public ConfidenceScores ConfidenceScores { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("length")]
            public int Length { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("offset")]
            public int Offset { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("relations")]
            public List<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("sentiment")]
            public string Sentiment { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Assessment
        {
            [JsonProperty("confidenceScores")]
            public ConfidenceScores ConfidenceScores { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("isNegated")]
            public bool IsNegated { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("length")]
            public int Length { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("offset")]
            public int Offset { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("sentiment")]
            public string Sentiment { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Sentence
        {
            [JsonProperty("targets")]
            public List<Target> Targets { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("confidenceScores")]
            public ConfidenceScores ConfidenceScores { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("length")]
            public int Length { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("offset")]
            public int Offset { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("assessments")]
            public List<Assessment> Assessments { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("sentiment")]
            public string Sentiment { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Doc
        {
            [JsonProperty("confidenceScores")]
            public ConfidenceScores ConfidenceScores { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("sentences")]
            public List<Sentence> Sentences { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("sentiment")]
            public string Sentiment { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("warnings")]
            public List<object> Warnings { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class SentimentResponse
        {
            [JsonProperty("documents")]
            public List<Doc> Docs { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("errors")]
            public List<object> Errors { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("modelVersion")]
            public string ModelVersion { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

According to the Azure Cognitive Services docs, the Text Sentiment Analysis API should be returning the following JSON response:

```json
    {
        "documents": [
            {
                "confidenceScores": {
                    "negative": 0,
                    "neutral": 0,
                    "positive": 1
                },
                "id": "1",
                "sentences": [
                    {
                        "targets": [
                            {
                                "confidenceScores": {
                                    "negative": 0,
                                    "positive": 1
                                },
                                "length": 10,
                                "offset": 6,
                                "relations": [
                                    {
                                        "ref": "#/documents/0/sentences/0/assessments/0",
                                        "relationType": "assessment"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "sentiment": "positive",
                                "text": "atmosphere"
                            }
                        ],
                        "confidenceScores": {
                            "negative": 0,
                            "neutral": 0,
                            "positive": 1
                        },
                        "length": 17,
                        "offset": 0,
                        "assessments": [
                            {
                                "confidenceScores": {
                                    "negative": 0,
                                    "positive": 1
                                },
                                "isNegated": false,
                                "length": 5,
                                "offset": 0,
                                "sentiment": "positive",
                                "text": "great"
                            }
                        ],
                        "sentiment": "positive",
                        "text": "Great atmosphere."
                    },
                    {
                        "targets": [
                            {
                                "confidenceScores": {
                                    "negative": 0.01,
                                    "positive": 0.99
                                },
                                "length": 11,
                                "offset": 37,
                                "relations": [
                                    {
                                        "ref": "#/documents/0/sentences/1/assessments/0",
                                        "relationType": "assessment"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "sentiment": "positive",
                                "text": "restaurants"
                            },
                            {
                                "confidenceScores": {
                                    "negative": 0.01,
                                    "positive": 0.99
                                },
                                "length": 6,
                                "offset": 50,
                                "relations": [
                                    {
                                        "ref": "#/documents/0/sentences/1/assessments/0",
                                        "relationType": "assessment"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "sentiment": "positive",
                                "text": "hotels"
                            }
                        ],
                        "confidenceScores": {
                            "negative": 0.01,
                            "neutral": 0.86,
                            "positive": 0.13
                        },
                        "length": 52,
                        "offset": 18,
                        "assessments": [
                            {
                                "confidenceScores": {
                                    "negative": 0.01,
                                    "positive": 0.99
                                },
                                "isNegated": false,
                                "length": 15,
                                "offset": 18,
                                "sentiment": "positive",
                                "text": "Close to plenty"
                            }
                        ],
                        "sentiment": "neutral",
                        "text": "Close to plenty of restaurants, hotels, and transit!"
                    }
                ],
                "sentiment": "positive",
                "warnings": []
            }
        ],
        "errors": [],
        "modelVersion": "2020-04-01"
    }
```

Here is my NewsSearch class:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    namespace SoccerStats
    {
        // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
        public class QueryContext
        {
            [JsonProperty("originalQuery")]
            public string OriginalQuery { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("adultIntent")]
            public bool AdultIntent { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Sort
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("isSelected")]
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Thumbnail
        {
            [JsonProperty("contentUrl")]
            public string ContentUrl { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("width")]
            public int Width { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("height")]
            public int Height { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Image
        {
            [JsonProperty("thumbnail")]
            public Thumbnail Thumbnail { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Provider
        {
            [JsonProperty("_type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("image")]
            public Image Image { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class About
        {
            [JsonProperty("readLink")]
            public string ReadLink { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Mention
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class NewsResult
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Headline { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string Url { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("description")]
            public string Summary { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("provider")]
            public List<Provider> Provider { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("datePublished")]
            public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("about")]
            public List<About> About { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("category")]
            public string Category { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("image")]
            public Image Image { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("mentions")]
            public List<Mention> Mentions { get; set; }
    
            public string Sentiment { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class NewsSearch
        {
            [JsonProperty("_type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("readLink")]
            public string ReadLink { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("queryContext")]
            public QueryContext QueryContext { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("totalEstimatedMatches")]
            public int TotalEstimatedMatches { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("sort")]
            public List<Sort> Sort { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("value")]
            public List<NewsResult> NewsResults { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message is saying that an integer was expected, but it got "0.64". Matching up the JSON with the class shows a mismatch: Your Negative, Neutral and Positive properties are `int` but the JSON has decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix ConfidenceScores class

```
 public class ConfidenceScores
        {
            [JsonProperty("negative")]
            public double Negative { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("neutral")]
            public double Neutral { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("positive")]
            public double Positive { get; set; }
        }
```

and I can see this code that looks as a bug for me

```
if (result.Headline == sentiment.Id)
{
double score;
if (double.TryParse(sentiment.Sentiment, out score))
{
result.SentimentScore = score;
}
   break;
}
```

sentiment is a string "positive" and you can not convert it to double. You will always have a default value 0;

you can try this

```
if (result.Headline == sentiment.Id)
{
if (sentiment.Sentiment=="positive")
result.SentimentScore = sentiment.ConfidenceScores.Positive;
 else if (sentiment.Sentiment=="negative")
result.SentimentScore = sentiment.ConfidenceScores.Negative;
else result.SentimentScore = sentiment.ConfidenceScores.Neutral;
   break;
}
```

and change Sentiment of NewsResult

```
public class NewsResult
{
.....
public double SentimentScore { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it! But now every sentiment score is displaying as 0. Somehow, I am not accessing the right thing in my Console.WriteLine in the Main method. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Pianoman Do you mean "sentiment": "positive" ?  Please tell me where is it?

Comment: Inside my `main` method this line:                         ```Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sentiment Score: {0} Date: {1:f}, Headline: {2}, Summary: {3} \r\n", result.SentimentScore, result.DatePublished, result.Headline, result.Summary));```

Comment: Here is an example of the output I'm getting: ```Sentiment Score: 0 Date: Sunday, October 17, 2021 12:00 AM,   ```

Comment: Every entry displays a Sentiment Score of 0.

Comment: @Pianoman I am trying to find NewsResult class. Where is it?

Comment: I realized I didn't include that class. Sorry! I edited my original question to add that class. I'm guessing the Sentiment no longer returns an actual score but an assessment of `Negative`, `Neutral`, or `Positive`. I was able to change my code to display those strings, but if there's a way to show an actual sentiment score, I would like to add that!

Comment: @Pianoman Can you post json for NewSearch class too pls?